# Sexuality in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a [Sexuality](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sexuality) proposal at area 51.

> Proposed Q&A site for proposed Q&A site for frank and clinical information on human sexuality.

Many of the questions could possibly live comfortably here.

Before I suggest on the Sexuality proposal that it is a dupe of Health, I wanted to check with the community here. Are there good reasons to include or exclude Sexuality in the scope of Health?

Comment: Related [here](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-glycerin-based-personal-lubricant) & [there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sexuality/75059#75059)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think Sexuality is a dupe of Health, though there may some overlap. Most of the top questions on the proposal would not be on-topic here. For example "How do I know what size condoms I need to buy?" and "I reach orgasm too soon during intercourse or foreplay. How can I delay it?"

Some of the questions will have overlap, such as "How much sex is too much? When does it become unhealthy (physically or mentally)?" and "Are there health risks to switching between anal and vaginal sex without a condom, given that both partners have been tested recently for STDs?" This won't be a problem though, as this happens with many SE sites, including here already.

So, don't close as a dupe. There is overlap, but not enough that a successful proposal should be shut down.

Answer (score 2):

I am in agreement that there will be some overlap, and there will be questions that can live comfortably on both sites.

However, there is a vast arena of sexuality that is not really related to personal or community health, and would be closed as off topic here. I think that there is enough information available that it would make a very viable proposal, and I think it should be allowed to stand on its own.